# extract a part of a URL dynamically in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

Working with selenium automation,I'm not able to extract the URL dynamically.How to extract a part of a URL dynamically,in selenium automation using Java?

Comment: You can use driver.getUrl  then by using regular expression.. you can extract required data from url

Comment: what do you mean by part of a URL dynamically ? what is the context of dynamic in your use case ?

Answer (score 1):

Using this:

`String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();`

you will get a string with current URL. For example: `https://stackoverflow.com/`. Let say you want to extract a part of this `stackoverflow`. Then you can use this sample code:

```
String s = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
String output = s.substring(8, 21); // 8 - begin index, 21 - end index
System.out.println(output); // prints 'stackoverflow'
```